# Copy SMS to SIM using Android SDK

Tags: android

I'm trying to reimplement the copy to SIM functionality on Android. I have tried the following code

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", "1234567");
values.put("body", "Message Content");
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/icc"), values);
```

but it returns invalid request "content://sms/icc". Could anyone tell if there is anyway to make this work. I'm using Android SDK 2.2.1

Comment: Did you use for the SMS?

Answer (score 0):

For manages Message from this : 
You can use the little example:
[Manage SIM Message](http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/mms/ui/ManageSimMessages.java.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i need to copy the sms from the phone memory to sim rather than the other way round